# Why the outputs of a value in Jupiter sometime is correct, and some times not?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have written a code which was calculating a measure correctly for a specific data correctly. But after some time, some of the values are not shown correctly. 
The generated measure is between 0 and 1 (which was  0.8998 for few times of running); however, it shows -4.486000218950312e+183  value for the same data, which somethin irrelevant and generated by machine. Calculating Dice score by using `medpy` library:

```
import medpy.metric.binary as metrics
mean_dsc=np.ndarray(no_slices,dtype=float)
for i in range(no_slices)
      segm=res_vol[:,:,i]
      gt=lbl[:,:,i] 
      mean_dsc[i]=metrics.dc(segm, gt)
print mean_dsc
```

What is the reason for this? Is there any bug with jupyter or python? How can i resolve this issue?

your help is appreciated

Comment: Can you include your code in the question?

Comment: @el323 I updated

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue with this, the problem was that I was creating the array like this:

```
mean_dsc=np.ndarray(no_slices,dtype=float)
```

I changed it as creating array by `np.zeros()` instead of `np.ndarray`.